# Flask/jinja, adding radio buttons to a selectpicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, radio-button, bootstrap-select

Apologies in advance if I hack up the formatting, let alone show off the massive hole in my understanding of things.

Anywho, I scoured stackoverflow and managed to cobble together a dropdown that dynamically fills from mongo, and then faithfully passes back the user selection to make another mongo call that populates a motionchart.  All's well.

Now all I was hoping to do was slip in a few radio buttons to pass along a single choice as the secondary dimension (first dimension from dropdown).

No worries, right?  Ha!  Not so much...

I've not been able to find a single example of mixed inputs/actions (GET and POST) in a single form/input group, so while I've tried my best to intelligently tinker, I don't think I know enough yet to know.

Many thanks in advance! Very much looking forward to learning how it all needs to get wired up to function properly...

Here's the app call:

```
 @frontend.route('/orgs_by_ic_motion', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 @login_required
 def orgs_by_ic_motion():
    button = "$ORG_NAME"
    if request.method == 'POST':   
        if request.form['submit'] == 'ACT':
            button = request.form['choice1']  
        elif request.form['submit'] == 'ORG':
            button = request.form['choice1']          

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        db2 = conn.orgs9.ic_list.find({},{'_id':0})
        json2 = json.dumps(list(db2), default=json_util.default)
        df_ic = pd.read_json(json2, orient='records')
        df_ic.sort_index(by=['Group2', 'IC_NAME'], inplace=True)
        ic_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for row in df_ic.itertuples():
            ic_dict[row[4]].append([row[5], row[1]])
       selected_ic = request.args.get('selectedic')
       data_list = []
       if not isinstance(selected_ic, type(None)):
           rep_all = reporter_all.aggregate([
            {'$match': {'IC_NAME':selected_ic}},
            {'$group': {
                "_id": {
                'org_name': button,
                'fy': "$FY"},
                'grant_sum': {'$sum': '$TOTAL_COST'},
                'sub_sum': {"$sum": 'TOTAL_COST_SUB_PROJECT'},
                'grant_cnt': {'$sum': 1}}},
            {'$sort': {'grant_sum':-1}}])
        df = pd.DataFrame(rep_all['result'])
        if not isinstance(df, type(None)):
            for row in df.itertuples():
                for k,v in row[1].iteritems():
                    df.loc[row[0], k] = v
            df['total_sum'] = df[['grant_sum', 'sub_sum']].sum(axis=1)
            df.drop(['_id','grant_sum','sub_sum'], axis=1, inplace=True)
            for row in df.itertuples():
                data_list.append([row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]])

    conn.close()
    return render_template('google/orgs_by_ic_motion.html', data=data_list, butt=button, ic=ic_dict, req=selected_ic)
```

And here's the page:

```
    <script src="../../static/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../static/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/bootstrap-select.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'motionchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

      var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data_table.addColumn('string', 'IC');
      data_table.addColumn('number', 'Year');
      data_table.addColumn('number', 'Records');
      data_table.addColumn('number', 'Costs');
      data_table.addRows([
                {%- for cnt, ic, fy, sums in data %}
                ['{{ ic }}', {{fy}}, {{cnt}}, {{sums}}],
                {%- endfor %}
        ]);

        var opts = {};  
        opts['height'] = 500;
        opts['width'] = 800;
        var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(
                document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data_table, opts, {allowHtml:true});
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container' id='main-container'>
<div class='content'>
<div class='container-fluid' style='font: 12px sans-serif;'>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <h4>Institutes & Centers</h4>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method=["GET","POST"] action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <select name="selectedic" id="selectedic" class="selectpicker form-control selectedic" show-tick data-width='auto' data-selected-text-format="count>1" data-live-search="true" title='Make a selection from below...'>
                {% for k,v in ic.items() %}
                <optgroup label = {{k}}>
                {% for ic in v|sort %}
                    <option>{{ic[0]}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </optgroup>
              {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <div id="radios1" class="btn-group view-opt-btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="choice1" value="$ORG_NAME">Organisations</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="choice1" value="$ACTIVITY">Activity</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="choice1" value={{request.form['choice1']}}/>
        </div>
        <script type="text/jscript">
            $("body").find("#radios1").children().each(function () {
                $(this).bind('click', function () {
                    $("input[name=choice1]").val(this.value);
                    });
            });
        </script>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
{{butt}}
    </div>  
        <div class="result"></div>   
        </div>      
    <h3 class="text-muted">{{req}}</h3>
    <h6>Click play <i class="fa fa-play"></i> button below to start animation</h6>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="muted credit">
            <h5>Inspired by <a hef='http://www.gapminder.org'>GapMinder</a></br>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('select[name=selectedic]').val(1);
$('.selectedic').selectpicker('refresh');
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: i figured it out, or perhaps more accurately, I got it to work--  if I rip out the conditional tests to request.method and all it seems to work fine, but that's not exactly the same as understanding.